# Laravel 5.1 and Bootstrap 3 Sass setup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

I want to use Bootstrap 3 Sass with Laravel 5.1, but I had some questions:

- In 5.1, in the package.json file for Laravel, out-of-the-box there is
  a dependency for "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0". Is there an easy way
  then to set up bootstrap sass with Laravel 5.1?
- Do I need to pull in the bootstrap source or should I just link to
  the CDN or put the files in my public folder?
- Is there any reason to use the source code of Bootstrap, instead of
  putting it in the public folder?
- Am I correct in assuming that I would need to install bootstrap
  through Bower, move the fonts folder contents to the public folder,
  then set up Elixir to mix all the Sass files together?

I'm just a bit confused about integrating a third party front end service like Bootstrap into Laravel. I'm new to both Laravel and Bootstrap, so any information or advice would be appreciated.

Note: I've done a lot of research online, but the tutorials for Laravel and Bootstrap are dated and the comments reveal that they don't work right.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First to install the node packages just run `npm install` inside the folder.

After that if you navigate to `resources/assets/sass/app.scss` you will see the first commented line imports entire bootstrap from node modules installed through `package.json`

After you've uncommented the line you can see by default in `gulpfile.js` you already have the elixir command to compile the app sass file.

With all that setup just run `gulp` and elixir will compile the sass file that imports bootstrap and you will see the output in `public/css/app.css` which you can link in your application.

And finally to copy the fonts or any other asset you can use the `copy` command and you will have the fonts copied to the public folder.

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.copy('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/', 'public/fonts');
    mix.sass('app.scss'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Altrim, I appreciate your time!

Comment: And what about the other source files and scripts like bootstrap.js. Do I mix it in directly from the gulpfile.js? Like so: `../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js`?

Comment: how does linkage to the fonts work? i.e. how does bootstrap know the fonts are in public/fonts?

Comment: @Shane If you look at bootstrap source you can see by default bootstrap includes the fonts from `../fonts/`. In this case basically the dir structure is the same as the default you get when downloading bootstrap. In this case the css is in `pubilc/css/` folder and we copy the fonts to `public/fonts/`.

Comment: @CurvianVynes I guess you can do that but I usually first copy `mix.copy()` the js files to `/resources/assets/js/` and then I mix them from there.